# How to place a div outside the upper right corner of my form using bootsrap?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I got a form, and it displays some detail text about stuff in my application.
Outside this form, I have a "add new item" button, which the user can click on to go to a new page to add a new item.

This button is now placed on the upper left side corner outside of the form, and I'd like to move it to the other side (the right upper corner of the form).

In this case my button is the `<router-link>` since I'm using Vue.js, and the routing works fine, and it styles as a button.

I use bootstrap-4 in my vue.js application with css-only property.

I've tried "float: right; ", and adding

```
<div class="row"> <div class="col"></div></div>
```

to "force" the button to move through columns, but it doesen't work.

So this is how my code looks like now:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="details">
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-md-center">
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col create-new-item-button">
         <div class="">
           <router-link
             class="btn btn-primary"
             style="margin-bottom: 30px"
             :to="{ name: 'Create new item' }"
           >Create new item </router-link>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
       <form>
<p>Text in my form and other stuff</p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My css (other than bootstrap's own):

```
.details {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

form {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black; 

}

.create-new-item-button {
  float: right;
}
```

What should I do to move it to make it to the upper right corner, outside the form?

Comment: Have you looked into positioning elements with flex box? Flex box comes with bootstrap 4 and has made life a lot easier without having to use floats. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: You could move the button to after your form in the markup.

Comment: @FrankA yes, I did. I've tried some of it, and it still doesen't go my way...
This codepen does illustrate how it looks like to me: 
[link] (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNXxxb) and now when it is absolute positioned, it is too far away from the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute; right: 0;` to the div with the class row on your custom css, just like this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNXxxb

I just added the "my-custom-class" to the row and edited it on the css

Comment: Ok, so I tried your suggestion and it does move the button. Although, It is way out to the right and not near the form when it displays in the browser.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNXxxb
 can you see that I added a black solid border around my form?
I want t the button to display just where the upper right corner is

Comment: Well, since position: absolute assumes the position relative to the father element, in this case, it won't work cause your button is outside the form. If you want your button on the right side of the FORM element, first you need to put the button container inside it. I made some changes to my pen and used flexbox and justify-content to align the button container. Take a look: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrOJKK?editors=1100

Comment: yes, I want it on the right side of the form. But in this case it is inside of the form. I'd like it to have this position, but outside the borders of the form.

Comment: In this case, just wrap the button and the form into a father element :)

Comment: Ok, But you don't add anything in the css to the items-wrapper class? you just change: 
``.create-new-item-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}``

Comment: No need to. I just wrapped them into a father element so it will "delimit" the children elements, and with this you can align everything inside it by telling that the children must respect the position and width of the father element

Answer (score 2):

if you want to put it outside `.details` try to give it `position: absolute;` `left: 100%;`

Comment: So wierd, it doesen't work when I do that.... I lifted out the eintire ``<div class="row"> <div class="col create-new-item-button">
         <div class="">
           <router-link></router-link></div></div></div> ```

the entire thing dissapered, and did not display

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve what you want by wrapping the button with anything displayed as *block*, e.g., `<p />`, `<div />` and make its `text-align:right;`. No floating, no absolute positioning needed.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="details">
        <p class="text-right">
            <router-link
              class="btn btn-primary"
              style="margin-bottom: 30px"
              :to="{ name: 'Create new item' }"
            >Create new item </router-link>
        </p>
        <form>
            <p>Text in my form and other stuff</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution came to this:

I took your advice and figured stuff out. So, I moved the entire section of the button (column and everything) and placed it under the `</form`>` tag.

Now it looks like this:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="details">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-md-center">
        <form>
<p> Text in my form and other stuff</p>
     </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
         <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
            <div class="col ml-auto p-2 ">
                <router-link
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                  style="margin-bottom: 30px"
                  :to="{ name: 'Create new item' }"
                >Create new item</router-link>

            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Thank you all for your help!